# @RequestAttribute in springMVC is not binding Object of Entitiy class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to spring,i am trying to develop basic java project with spring MVC using Annotations,i am trying to create an object of my Entity class(Information.java) in the controller using @RequestAttribute and send it to the view,my code as follows

My controller class

```
 package org.practice.spring;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

    @Controller()
    public class HelloController
    {

        @RequestMapping("/hello")
        public ModelAndView helloWorld(@RequestAttribute Information userInfo) 
        {


            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
            model.addObject("firstname", userInfo.getFirstName());
            model.addObject("lastname", userInfo.getLastName());
            return model;
        }

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public ModelAndView homePage() {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index", "info", new Information());
            return model;
        }
    }
```

My Entity class

```
package org.practice.spring;

public class Information {
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    private String lastName;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
   }
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hello,Please Enter Name</h3>
<form:form action="hello" modelAttribute="info">
First Name:<form:input path="firstName"/><br>
Last Name:<form:input path="lastName"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
<h3>Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

and Tomcat is giving me this

> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
>   WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing request attribute 'userInfo' of type Information]

When i run the application browser is giving me this

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request Type Status Report
>
> Message Missing request attribute 'userInfo' of type Information
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

So far i dont have any syntax errors in my code,but my code is not working,i struck here for almost 2 days,did alot of googling but no luck,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant to use @PathVariable instead...

Comment: How about using from @RequestAttribute to @ModelAttribute("info") in your helloWorld method?

Comment: Thanks for the response,i am following a tutorial on udemy and the instructor is using this annotation to develop the application,i code exactly like him but its not working for me,if i use any other annotation i would break the link to the project

Comment: Then the tutorial is wrong. For binding you must use `@ModelAttribute` and hence this is an exact duplicate as the other question.

Comment: your solution is working, I hope it won't give me any issues in further, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: @RequestAttribute(name="info").

Comment: Thanks,i tried @RequestAttribute(name="info") and i am getting "Missing request attribute 'info' of type Information" now.